# i need make an INSERT INTO tablex (SELECT columns)VALUES(v1...vn)

Tags: oracle, plsql

I need to make an "insert dynamically" random data in table `WORKER`, now I have the fieldname, the datatype and the size of every column of this table `WORKER` in other table `TEMPORAL` (this info was captured before and saved on this table).

The question is: when I make the insert, I need to know the fields from this table to make the insert. How do I do it? How do I take the values from `TEMPORAL` to make the insert? Until now I got this but doesn't work:

```
insert into worker(select chr(500)||upper(name)||',' from temporal)
```

I thought about this too:

```
select chr(500)||upper(name)||',' from temporal
```

or make a dynamic statement using this values and a cursor.

thx to everibody.

TEMPORAL contains the name, the datatype and the length of the table TRABAJADOR, captured for do the insertion of random data. but i most to do this dynamically for that reason i don't know what or how much columns this table had(i have to do this for every or any table on any shema). this is what temporal contains:

### NAME          Typ              Length

ID_MAN        NUMBER            22
SALARIO       NUMBER            22
GENERO        VARCHAR2          8
FDN           DATE              7
NOMBRE        VARCHAR2          100
DIRECCION     VARCHAR2          60
DEPT          VARCHAR2          60
PAIS          VARCHAR2          60
CATEGORIA     VARCHAR2          60

i got right now in one variable(COL) the names of the columns for pass into the insert statement
insert into worker(col). but i dont know how to do this or if even is posible. THX

Comment: Can you please give us an example of what `TEMPORAL` contains and what you should see as result in `WORKER` ?

Comment: TEMPORAL contains the name, the datatype and the length of the table TRABAJADOR, captured for the insertion of random data. but i most to do this dynamically for that reason i don't know what or how much columns this table had(i have to do this for every or any table on any shema). this is what temporal contains:

Comment: i response your answer in the question because i dont know how doit in another place and de comments mos be shorts. sorry for the english

Comment: i solve this  troble now because i dont need this info in the insert statement.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that with dynamic SQL. This should work:

```
declare
  myQuery varchar2(4000);
begin
  -- Open insert and aggregate all values
  select 'insert into worker('
         || listagg(t.name, ', ') within group (order by t.name)
  into myQuery
  from TEMPORAL t;

  -- Close insert
  myQuery := myQuery  || ') values(<here you have to specify your values>)';

  execute immediate myQuery;
end;
/
```

Comment: it give me an eror in the here:                                     within group

Comment: Can you please try again? I had forgotten to remove the `end loop`.

Comment: stil the same it Oracle sql developer mark this:    within group   whit red it doesn't letme execute

Comment: Oh... what is your version of Oracle ?

Comment: i'm using the version 11 express